# Writing custom sections into app.config

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I want to save some custom data into application configuration file and I need to create some custom sections in app.config. Reading custom data from app.config is simple task, but I can't write information from my programm into app.config.
For finding solution of this problem I create test project.

For reading data from custom section app.config I used information from this article:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2006/11/13/app-config-and-custom-configuration-sections.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First override `IsReadyOnly()` in your `CustomConfigSection` to return false.

Once you've done that you should be able to do something like this (this is for ASP.NET, but it might be transferably):

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
CustomConfigSection config = (CustomConfigSection)configFile.GetSection("Custom");
config.Tweak = 1;
config.Change = "foo";
configFile.Save();
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Do you mean override `IsReadOnly()` to return `false`?

Answer (score 5):

You really ought not to write anything to `app.config`, because if you do then you are limiting use of your app to Administrators only. It's better practice to write settings to a separate `.config` file located in a user profile folder, e.g. `<profiles>\<user name>\Application Data\<your product name>`.

Comment: Thanks. I think that user of application need read and write permissions only. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: To clarify: the `app.config` file is installed into a folder underneath Program Files. By default this is set up to not allow write access to standard users. Although .NET will happily allow you to write to any `.config` file via the normal Configuration API, if you actually try it running as a standard user then you will get a security exception.

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember this. I'll use oportunity for writing into app.config for my windows services not for desktop application.