# Dynamically add and remove key-value pairs from a section in app.config

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, app-config

My XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="databaseTypes" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="dataDictionary" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <databaseTypes>
    <add key="ExampleServerPrefix_T" value="Connection_String_For_ExampleServer" />
    <add key="ExampleServer2Prefix_T" value="Connection_String_For_ExampleServer_2" />
    <add key="COPYLIVE_" value="ODBC;DSN=s2;" />
  </databaseTypes>
  <dataDictionary>
    <!-- Other pairs in this section -->
  </dataDictionary>
</configuration>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to add and remove key-value pairs from the `databaseTypes` section. So for example to would like to dynamically add a run time a new pair `<add key="blah" value="ODBC;blah" />`.

First its useful to know is this possible? If so how because I can't find any relevant documentation or examples on how this is done.

Comment: It is definitely possibly, I do it by implementing IConfigurationSectionHandler. Do you already have a databaseType class defined?

Comment: No I dont have one defined. Do I need one? I am only using it as a dictionary.

Comment: You don't have to it is just one way of doing it. Here is an article that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502091/writing-custom-sections-into-app-config

Comment: Here is another very good article: http://yizeng.me/2013/08/31/update-appsettings-and-custom-configuration-sections-in-appconfig-at-runtime/

Comment: @Kevin very good article, thank you. This article has partially solved my problem. I have it implemented and it is "saving" the new key-value pairs excepting it is really saving it. The new key-value pairs are saved in memory untill the program has finished executing it is never actually written to the XML file. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kevin apologies, it is working perfectly. That article helped solve my problem. Add it as an answer if you want rep

Comment: glad you got it all figured out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben,

Here are two articles that will help you with adding key/value pairs to the config:

Writing custom sections to app.config

[Writing custom sections into app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502091/writing-custom-sections-into-app-config)

Update AppSettings and custom configuration sections in App.config at runtime

http://yizeng.me/2013/08/31/update-appsettings-and-custom-configuration-sections-in-appconfig-at-runtime/